# How can I assign variable from json?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, variables

So my codes are like below;

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/gxs81',function(data){
$.each(data.employees,function(i,emp){
$('ul').append('<li>'+emp.firstName+' '+emp.lastName+'</li>');
});
```

I have multiple objects in json file, how can I assign them in an array? e.g.

`array[2][0]=*firstName field should be here*`

`array[2][1]=*lastname field should be here*`

Comment: Seems you already have an array....not at all clear what you are asking or wanting to accomplish. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve] then edit question with proper details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple push() to build a new array from your JSON:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/gxs81',function(data){
  var current = '';
  var myarray = [];
  $.each(data.employees,function(i,emp){
    current = emp.firstName+' '+emp.lastName;
    $('ul').append('<li>'+current+'</li>');
      myarray.push(current);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```